# Grid values deletion exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I am trying to delete values from grid in VB.NET with following code:

```
 Protected Sub gv_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDeleting

            Dim index As Integer = gv.EditIndex

            Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(gv.Rows(e.RowIndex), GridViewRow)

            Dim id As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gv.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())

            'Dim Id As Integer = Integer.Parse(DirectCast(gv.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtId"), TextBox).Text)

            gc.ExecuteCommand("delete from expence where id= '" & Id & "' ")

            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>alert('Data Updated')</script>")

            gv.EditIndex = -1

            bindGrid()


        End Sub
```

It is giving me exception on line `Dim id As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gv.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())` as follows:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
```

I dont know why this exception is comming.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't defined `DataKeys` property in gridview ,you should define `DataKeys="id"` in your gridview..